Select empty fields of csv
I'm testing regular expressions in a CSV but I've run into a problem that I'm not able to solve.
The case is that for example I have to select the rows that have the fifth empty field out of a total of 6.
The CSV is separated by commas.
Example CSV:
datetime,car,brand,model,km,new
10/10/1949 20:30,yes,ford,f150,,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,,yamaha,r7,,yes
,yes,renault,twingo,,yes
10/10/1949 20:30,no,honda,cbr600rr,2000,no

and i have this regular expression:
^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,,.+$

But of course, this works only if all the fields before the fifth one have data, if any of them is empty it doesn't match and I can't find a way to make it match whether or not there are empty fields before the fifth field.
In this example, it should select lines 1,2 and 3.
Could you help me?
Thank you very much.
Best regards.

+ matches one or more, * matches zero or more.

Thank you very much, with your comment i can solve this, im really happy, thank you, have a good day!
